# Wifi disconnects due to "idling" on college wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

My college wifi kicks the user off the network if they aren't actively using the internet (although the user is still connected to the network, the user gets redirected to the sign-in portal). Is there a way to prevent this? Perhaps something that regularly sends let's say a ping, to prevent the wifi connect from closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is with a `cron` job.

```
crontab -e
```

If it asks for an editor, just hit enter and continue. Add a line like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/ping -c1 8.8.8.8
```

This will ping `8.8.8.8` once every 5 minutes. Hopefully 5 minutes is a small enough period of time that it won't kick you out, but you can reduce the interval if needed.

Answer (score 0):

How long does the connection last?  I'll assume it's 5 minutes.  5 times 60 seconds is 300 seconds.  A little less than that would be 250 seconds, so, using the IP address of Google's servers, open a command window and type:

```
ping -i 250 8.8.8.8
```

or

```
ping -i 250 8.8.4.4
```

Just leave the window open while you're working at school and you won't be disconnected IF a ping is enough activity.  If you need an http request, you can run wget or curl from a chron job to download a (hopefully small) web page, maybe from your college web site.  It might be more polite to ping a college IP address than Google, but if you set the timeout long enough it won't matter much.